# Memory leak warning when using Redirect

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redirect, redux, react-redux

I use Firebase for authentication with React and Redux. The sign-up component works without errors until I use `Redirect`.

I have `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` in Layout component and use `Redirect` in `Route` App.js

How to solve the memory leak warning issue?

[image]

**Layout component**

```
unsubscribeFromAuth = null;

componentDidMount() {
    const { setCurrentUser } = this.props;
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (userAuth) => {
        if (userAuth) {
            const userRef = await createUserProfileDocument(userAuth);

            userRef.onSnapshot((snapShot) => {
                setCurrentUser(
                    {
                        id: snapShot.id,
                        ...snapShot.data(),
                    },
                    () => {
                        console.log(this.state);
                    }
                );
            });
        }

        setCurrentUser(userAuth);
    });
}

// Close subscription
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth();
}
```

**Redux in Layout component**

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        setCurrentUser: (user) => dispatch(setCurrentUser(user)),
    };
};
```

**App.js**

```
<Route
    exact
    path='/signinsignup'
    render={() =>
    currentUser ? <Redirect to='/' /> : <SignInAndSignUpPage />
    }
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll also need to unsubscribe from `userRef.onSnapshot`.

```js
unsubscribeFromAuth = null;
unsubscribeFromOnSnapshot = null

componentDidMount() {
    const { setCurrentUser } = this.props;
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (userAuth) => {
        if (userAuth) {
            const userRef = await createUserProfileDocument(userAuth);

            this.unsubscribeFromOnSnapshot = userRef.onSnapshot((snapShot) => {
                setCurrentUser(
                    {
                        id: snapShot.id,
                        ...snapShot.data(),
                    },
                    () => {
                        console.log(this.state);
                    }
                );
            });
        }

        setCurrentUser(userAuth);
    });
}

// Close subscription
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth();
    if (this.unsubscribeFromOnSnapshot) {
        this.unsubscribeFromOnSnapshot();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it still shows the error.